# wget is not able to get the correct ssl certifiicate expiration date

Tags: ssl, wget

When I execute this

```
wget -O /root/installer.php https://www.grscripts.com/install/installer.deluxe
```

I receive this error

```
ERROR: cannot verify https://www.grscripts.com's/ certificate, issued by â€˜/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3â€™:   Issued certificate has expired.
```

but it's not true , indeed http://www.grscripts.com's/ certificate is ok and will expire on Feb 2022. Why wget is failing to get the correct certificate and how to fix it ?

Note that I know that I can skip the problem with --no-check-certificate , I would know why wget is reporting that the certificate is expired while it's not expired.

Comment: Are you checking this on the same machine you ran wget on? If not, did you check the date on the machine?

Comment: different machines , the date is correct .

Comment: run `wget -S` and check if the correct IP is resolved.

Comment: ip is correct , 94.130.76.170

Comment: In the error message, why there is no "S" on the URL, only http ?

Comment: checked , this is error returned "cannot verify https://www.grscripts.com's/ certificate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't update your system and root certificates then it is possible that your system won't be able to recognize Let's Encrypt certificates.
See list [Let's Encrypt compatibility list](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/#platforms-that-trust-dst-root-ca-x3-but-not-isrg-root-x1)

Comment: it's a fresh Centos 7 installation. BTW how to update "root certificates" ?

Comment: You need to have the latest `ca-certificates` package.

Comment: yum reinstall ca-certificates  , fixed the problem thank you are a genius